# Cannot create payouts with an OAuth key

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using below payout method

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_**********");
try {
    $return_data = \Stripe\Payout::create([
        "amount" => 1000,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "description" => "STRIPE PAYOUT FOR TESTING",
    ],["stripe_account" => "acct_******"]);
    print_r($return_data);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

It's giving me errors to say - **Cannot create payouts with an OAuth key.**

A user connecting to my app using below URL:

> https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id='
>   . STRIPE_CLIENT_ID . '&scope=read_write&redirect_uri=

If I'm using the direct secret key of that account then it works fine. so only issue with when I'm using a secret key that I got using OAuth

Here is a method that I'm using https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

Not sure if it allows me to create a payout or not or if yes then why it's not working. Can anyone have an idea about this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Standard Connected accounts. With these account types, the platform actually doesn't have access to create payouts on behalf of the Standard account. Platforms can only create payouts on Express or Custom connected accounts as they are managed by the platform while Standard accounts are managed entirely by the owner of the account. This is why you are able to create the payout with the Standard accounts API key and not with your platform accounts API key. They've got a good breakdown of platform permissions based on account type here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#choosing-an-approach